# Is there a Python library for handling complicated mathematical sets (constructed using mathematical set-builder notation)?

Tags: python, data-structures, set, generator, lazy-sequences

I often work with multidimensional arrays whose array indices are generated from a complicated user-specified set.

I'm looking for a library with classes for representing complicated sets with an arbitrary number of indices, and arbitrarily complicated predicates. Given a set description, the desired output would be a generator. This generator would in turn produce either `dict`s or `tuple`s which correspond to the multidimensional array indices.

Does such a library exist?

---

**Example**

Suppose we had the following user-specified set (in [set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation)), which represents the indices of some array variable `x[i][j]`:

{i in 1..100, j in 1..50: i >= 20, j >= 21, 2*(i + j) <= 100}

I'd like to put this into some sort of a lazy class (a generator expression perhaps) that will allow me to lazily evaluate the elements of the set to generate the indices for my array. Suppose this class were called `lazyset`; this would be the desired behavior:

```
>>> S = lazyset("{i in 1..100, j in 1..50: i >= 20, j >= 21, 2*(i+j) <= 100}")
>>> S
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1f3e7d0>
>>> next(S)
{'i': 20, 'j': 21}
>>> next(S)
{'i': 20, 'j': 22}
```

I'm thinking I could roll my own using generator expressions, but this almost seems like a solved problem. So I thought I'd asked if anyone's come across an established library that handles this (to some extent, at least). Does such a library exist?

Comment: have a look at scipy and sympy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a constraint-solver problem to me:

```
import constraint as c

p = c.Problem()
p.addVariable(0, range(1,101))
p.addVariable(1, range(1,51))
p.addConstraint(lambda i: i >= 20, [0])
p.addConstraint(lambda j: j >= 21, [1])
p.addConstraint(c.MaxSumConstraint(50))

indices = ((s[0], s[1]) for s in p.getSolutionIter())  # convert to tuple generator
```

then if you do

```
for ij in indices:
    print ij
```

you get

```
(29, 21)
(28, 22)
(28, 21)
(27, 23)
(27, 22)
(27, 21)

...

(20, 25)
(20, 24)
(20, 23)
(20, 22)
(20, 21)
```

Comment: That is a certainly a creative idea! I hadn't thought of using a constraint solver to build the set. I can already see applications of python-constraint in other parts of my code. I'm just wondering however, if there was a more lightweight way of doing this, because I'm just looking to iterate through the indices, and then checking each index against all the predicates; if the particular index satisfies all the predicates, accept it, and if not reject it. I'm just wondering if the constraint-solver algorithm reduces to this case of affairs. Either way, it's a very creative idea!

Comment: @Gilead: `constraint` will evaluate each constraint as soon as the required variables are defined; in the worst case (all constraints depend on all variables), that is precisely what it reduces to.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not certain if this specifically (the set-builder notation) is supported by scipy. I think scipy is your best bet regardless.

There is support for sparse arrays/sets in scipy so you can easily let it handle the allocation of those without actually allocating the space :)

Comment: Thanks for your input, that certainly is an option that I hadn't thought of! However, I'm thinking of using generators because I don't intend to store these indices. I just want an iterable object that I can run `for` loops over.