# create a lambda function from a string **properly**

Tags: python, string, lambda

Given a string such as

```
"2*(i+j) <= 100"
```

I want to generate the corresponding lambda function,

```
fn = lambda i,j: 2*(i+j) <= 100
```

- I can do this with `eval`, but I am seeking a less evil method.
- I have found

  ```
  import ast
  f = ast.Lambda('i,j', '2*(i+j) <= 100')
  ```

  but I haven't figure out how to execute the result!
- Ideally, I would like to automatically pull out the parameter list ('i','j') as well - right now, I am just using re.findall('\w+'), but I would love to be able to properly use existing functions like `cos` instead of shadowing them as 'keywords'.

---

I was looking at [Is there a Python library for handling complicated mathematical sets (constructed using mathematical set-builder notation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110595/is-there-a-python-library-for-handling-complicated-mathematical-sets-constructe) and trying to figure out how best to parse the set-builder notation into the lambdas to feed to the constraint-solver.

I'm basically wishing for ast.literal_eval which would also recognize variables.

Ideally, given `i >= 20` I would like to get back `((lambda x: x >= 20), ['i'])` which I could then feed directly to `constraint`.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Are you making a gp read-interpret loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is from a **trusted source**, the *eval()* is the easiest, clearest, and most reliable way to go.

If your input is **untrusted**, then it needs to be **sanitized**.

One reasonable approach is the use of a regex. Make sure there are no function calls, attribute lookups, or double underscores in the string.

Alternatively, a more sophisticated approach is to walk the AST parse tree to determine whether there are any objectionable calls.

A third approach is to walk the AST parse tree and execute it directly.  That puts you in complete control over what gets calls.  The ast.literal_eval function takes this approach. Perhaps you start with its source and do some buildouts for any operations you want to support:

```
def literal_eval(node_or_string):
    """
    Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
    expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
    Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
    and None.
    """
    _safe_names = {'None': None, 'True': True, 'False': False}
    if isinstance(node_or_string, basestring):
        node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
    if isinstance(node_or_string, Expression):
        node_or_string = node_or_string.body
    def _convert(node):
        if isinstance(node, Str):
            return node.s
        elif isinstance(node, Num):
            return node.n
        elif isinstance(node, Tuple):
            return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, List):
            return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
        elif isinstance(node, Dict):
            return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
                        in zip(node.keys, node.values))
        elif isinstance(node, Name):
            if node.id in _safe_names:
                return _safe_names[node.id]
        elif isinstance(node, BinOp) and \
             isinstance(node.op, (Add, Sub)) and \
             isinstance(node.right, Num) and \
             isinstance(node.right.n, complex) and \
             isinstance(node.left, Num) and \
             isinstance(node.left.n, (int, long, float)):
            left = node.left.n
            right = node.right.n
            if isinstance(node.op, Add):
                return left + right
            else:
                return left - right
        raise ValueError('malformed string')
    return _convert(node_or_string)
```

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for an alternative to `eval`, but why? You're accepting arbitrary code and executing it anyway, so why not use `eval`?  The only reason to avoid `eval` is because it's dangerous, but the lambda you end up creating will be just as dangerous.

Also, keep in mind, [you really can't make it safe to do this in CPython](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: **Can't be done** is a phrase that rarely applies to Python.  The *ast.literal_eval* function is a fine example of how evaluate arbitrary code while limiting what you can accept.  Also, if the OP is working with *trusted* input, then *eval* or *exec* is perfectly reasonable (Guido uses them in the *timeit* module for example).

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is unsuitable for the OP's problem, since he wants expressions with evaluation in them.  My point here is to go ahead and use `eval`, it's dangerous, but so is his actual goal, so any other method will be equally dangerous.

Comment: Nice blog post.