# Printing a whole equation (including variables) in Python

Tags: python

say I want to print the equation g(x) in the form g(x) = x^2 *........

how do I do it? This is my first time using python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from sympy.mpmath import *



f = lambda x: ((x^2)*math.exp(-x))
dfdx = lambda x: diff(f,x)
d2fdx2 = lambda x: diff(dfdx,x)
g = lambda x: ((math.exp(x)/math.factorial(2))*d2fdx2)
print(g)
```

(edit) the output im getting is

function lambda at 0x0671C198

Comment: Wow, this doesn't look like a first time python user. Normally new users start with something more simple. Are you already familiar with another language??

Comment: Familiar with c++ and Java only. My math classes now require me to switch to learn python at a very fast rate and Im trying to cope

Comment: Alright kinda figured that I'm gonna read up on `lambda` real quick, so I can see what it does so I can  help. I have no experience with `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort!

Comment: Oh alright it's just like saying `def f(x):` time to start testing your code.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112046/create-a-lambda-function-from-a-string-properly) helps. I'm still testing with it.

Comment: I'll try using the eval function from your link, hold on

Comment: `eval` didn't work for me :/

Comment: yeah using eval did not work for me as well.. I know this is a simple thing but its really bothering me that I can't do it. All i want to do is output the equation in the form "x^2 + 2x + 2........... ".

Comment: I've found 2 answers: consists of putting the function in an entire separate module and the other is something I have no idea how to do [2](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Could you show me the one that you know how to do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334851/print-the-code-which-defined-a-lambda-function. Or do you want to have it formated more nicely?

Comment: Related: [How can I get the source code of a Python function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/427453/3821804)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes that just printed out what I set g to instead of solving the equation and outputting it. jepio already gave an answer that works but I just wanted you to know I appreciate your effort!

Comment: @Joe_Rose Thanks nice to know it was appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of drop all the the unnecessary imports and stick to what you really need. Symbolic math is what `sympy` was made for so check out the documentation for that.

In sympy you have to define `symbols` first

```
import sympy
x = symbols('x')
```

Now you would use the symbol `x` to construct an expression using builtin operators and functions in the `sympy` module. Be aware that `**` is exponentiation and `^` is logical xor.

```
f = x ** 2 * sympy.exp(-x)
dfdx = sympy.diff(f, x)
d2fdx2 = sympy.diff(f, x, x)
g = sympy.exp(x) / sympy.factorial(2) * d2fdx2
```

When you write `g` in the interactive interpreter it will write the expression the way you want it. Can't show that here but atleast I can do this:

```
>>> print(g)
x**2/2 - 2*x + 1
```

You cannot do what you want with the  `math`, `sympy.mpmath` and `numpy` modules as they exist for numerical evalutions - they want numbers and give you number.

If you later want to evaluate your expression for a given value of `x` you could do

```
val_at_point = g.evalf(subs={x: 1.5})
```

where `subs` is a dictionary.

Or you could turn `g` into a python lambda function:

```
fun_g = sympy.lambdify(x, g)
val_at_point = fun_g(1.5)
```

If you're doing this for a math class you probably want to be working in the interpreter anyway in which case you can start by writing

```
>>> from sympy import *
```

so that you can skip all the `sympy.` stuff in the above code samples. I left them there just to show where symbols come from.

Comment: Just when I was about to finish my own answer. Maybe you should show the `evalf` method, to see how one gets numbers.

Comment: And do not do the `from bla import *` import.

Comment: I'd disagree with the second comment: `from bla import *` is made for the interpreter and makes work much easier. In a module with many imports - never. But interactively its the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks jepio! Pointing out wrong library usage teaches me to dig into libraries next time to see what input arguements they take

Comment: and also your solution helped me get what I wanted!

Comment: @jepio: *interactively `from bla import *` is the only thing that makes sense*, except `from bla import a, b, c`.